# Actionbar how to change view on item click

Tags: android, adapter, android-actionbar, click

How can I change view of item in drop down navigation list in action bar on click?
After click, I want that displayed item shows another view (in layout it is set as invisible).
I've got `onNavigationItemSelected` method from `ActionBar.OnNavigationListener` but it does not pass view of the item clicked but just position of item in navigation spinner. Or in other words, why can I not get reference to selected view from actionbar spinner? (like I can get view with `listview  onItemClick` from `OnItemClickListener()`)

Answer (score 2):

`ActionBar`'s `Spinner` resource id is : `android:id/action_bar_spinner`

Get the `Spinner` resource id:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_spinner", "id", "android");
```

Get the reference to `Spinner` widget using the resource id:

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(resId);
```

Now you will be able to get access to the selected view:

```
CheckedTextView v = (CheckedTextView) spinner.getSelectedView();
```

You can modify the selected view right away in `OnNavigationListener`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(android.R.id.content, new MyFragment())
    .commit();

    SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.action_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_spinner", "id", "android");
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(resId);

    this.getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition,
                long itemId) {
            CheckedTextView v = (CheckedTextView) spinner.getSelectedView();
            // Modify selected view.
            return true;
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: how did you find what the resource id was?

Comment: Using DDMS `Dump View Hierarchy` feature.

Comment: resId = 0 from this. I'm using the real actionbar too (no compat mode stuff)

Comment: @CQM I've pasted `onCreate` code. resId has to be retreived after calling `setNavigationMode`. Let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: its in my onCreateView within my fragment and after `setNavigationMode`, all my actionbar configurations pertain to this fragment and happen within its lifecycle. Still getting resId = 0

Comment: @CQM Strange. For debugging purpose, can you try taking `View Hierarchy` screenshot using DDMS. Through that you will get the id.

Comment: it worked on the Nexus 5 but not the Nexus 4 or some other devices for me, also different versions of android

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to figure this out and managed to track it down.

Use [`setSelectedNavigationItem`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setSelectedNavigationItem%28int%29) to do this.

Comment: Thanks but method setSelectedNavigationItem just sets selected item in action bar spinner navigation. What I need is a need a way to get reference to selected item view in spinner (the one which is shown selected at action bar spinner) and then modify it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

With your navigationListener, you can try this :

```
OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    View convertView = null;
    View view = adapter.getView(itemPosition, convertView, null);
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) view
        .findViewById(R.id.my_textView);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), myTextView.getText(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
  }
```

You are then retrieving the item via the adapter. My only problem is now modifying the retrieved reference content. I can't seem to have it working.

I Hope it helps

Comment: yep this doesn't work, seems like its on the right track though